# Spring batch implementation strategy for one reader and multiple concurrent processors

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to implement Spring Batch Job.

My scenario is following: I have around 1mln records in database. For each of them i want to do some business operation just once. That operation may fail. After job execution i would like to have some job result (maybe in txt file) that contains Ids (or some other info like fail reason) of records with unsuccessfull operation.

I can build some basic reader - processor - writer scenario, but my time for this operation is quite limited so I was thinking about some optimizations.

I was thinking about getting multiple records at once (e.g. 100) and processing those records by multiple (eg. 5) processors.

I tried to use some basic implementations, but I failed to ensure one read operation for multiple records and concurrent processing.

Im also looking for some way to ensure that each record wont be processed twice.

Any ideas? What do you think about my approach?

Comment: Why would you need to build something for it? You can set the concurrency of the chunk/step. Properly configure skipping/error handling and it will work. It should be a matter of configuration you shouldn't need anything custom for this.

Comment: maybe I expressed my thoughts wrong but im not thinking about anything custom. Can you tell me how to achieve one multi records reader, split it into multiple parts and process separately using configuration?

Comment: You don't need to split anything, as stated just configure concurrency for your chunk (which is explained in the reference guide). What you would need to write is a `SkipListener` that registers the skipped records (but that is also a matter of configuration). You can configure a `TaskExecutor` on your step and have multiple threads handle records. In addition configure the skips and a skiplistener and you have what you want. It will do multiple reads in different threads as well as the processing and writing.

Comment: Ok, but it execute select statement for each single record, right? I would like to minimalize reading data step. Is it a good idea?

Comment: No it doesn't that depends on your reader, if you configured the JDBC cursor one, you specify a page size of how many to read.